# RecyclerView not working inside a ScrollView properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

My app and the `RecyclerView` was working fine until I add the second `RecyclerView` on to the fragment. Since I added the second fragment, I added a `ScrollView` to the fragment. Then I faced some issue with the scrolling within the recyclerview, it didn't scroll smoothly. After going through a lot of articles online including StackOverflow, I changed the `ScrollView` with `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`. This fixed the issue with scrolling but some major issue occured. The loading of items in the `RecyclerView` took more time, when I hit the searchbutton, that's there on the menu bar at the top, it took long time to expand the search field and some times app show 'not responding' message. Some articles say add `.setNestedScrollingEnabled=false` and I added it like the following in `onCreateView()` of the fragment. But I am still facing the issue.

I am using `kotlin`

```
binding.rv_home_items.isNestedScrollingEnabled=false
binding.rv_home_categories.isNestedScrollingEnabled=false
```

Following is the `xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorOffWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ui.fragments.HomeFragment">
    
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_home_categories"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp" />
    
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibutton_show_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_show_category" />
    
        </FrameLayout>
    
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout_category">
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
                    android:id="@+id/image_slider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
                    app:iss_corner_radius="5"
                    app:iss_delay="0"
                    app:iss_error_image="@color/colorDarkGrey"
                    app:iss_period="2500"
                    app:iss_placeholder="@color/colorDarkGrey"
                    app:iss_selected_dot="@drawable/default_selected_dot"
                    app:iss_unselected_dot="@drawable/default_unselected_dot"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />
    
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_home_items"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image_slider"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am completely stuck on my project, any help with this is highly appreciated

Edit:

When I launch the app, in a few seconds it's shows a message that the app is not responding.

Comment: `bindingView.recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
        bindingView.recyclerView.isFocusableInTouchMode = true`

Comment: I added this for both the `recyclerView`s in the `onCreateView()` but it didn't solve the issue. Any other suggestions? Am I supposed to add this in the `onCreateView()`?

Comment: Where am I supposed to add `bindingView.recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false`, I added this in the `onCreateView()` of the `fragment`. Is that correct?

Comment: I am completely stuck on my project, any help with this is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one `RecyclerView` and even all of them have same scroll direction, seems [ConcatAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter) can be preferred solution.

`ConcatAdapter` enables sequentially combine multiple adapters to a single `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Both `RecyclerView` has different scrolling direction. Can you suggest any other solution to fix the problem?

Comment: I believe `ConcatAdapter` can work for `RecyclerView` with different scrolling direction as well

Comment: Thanks for your response and I will give it a try next time when I update my app since it requires a lot of changes in code to implement `ConcatAdapter`. But for now, I need a fix/solution to solve the issue with my current layout.